# Powershell throwing error when passing a argument to Import-Csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, importerror

i'am trying to read a CSV file to pull out a field which is placed on a network. I'am getting the below error

```
Import-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Header'.
At D:\Apps\AP\Ex_Accounts\Account_Extract.ps1:1 char:29
```

when i execute the following in a PS script

```
$source="\\fmkir41m\folder\Data1\citi.txt"
$destimation="\\fmkir41m\folder\Data1\accounts.txt"
Import-CSV "$source" -Header (1..25) | Select-Object '4' | Out-File $destination
```

am i passing the the argument correctly for a file on the network? because it works if i give the path to the same file on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using PowerShell 2.0?